# Why does my Message Processor not trigger and read messages from the RabbitMQ Queue?

Tags: rabbitmq, wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I'm trying to get a Getting Started scenario to work, specifically the one about Guaranteed Delivery. I have followed the steps as described in the readme. When I sent the message from PostMan, I do receive a 202 from the server. In addition, I do see the message come in on the Rabbit Queue. However, that's where the process seems to stall: I never get the log from the endpoint. The message processor does not pick up the message from the message store.

I followed the readme that is attached to the Getting Started - Guaranteed Delivery-module. I can't find it online, but when you unpack the module in the Integration Studio, you should easily find it.

I've tried reinstalling, but I get the same problem. I feel it might be that the processor is immediately switched off, but I would not know where to turn it on properly. Does anybody have any idea?

**Edited to add:** A solution was provided to the processor immediately switching off (https://github.com/wso2/micro-integrator/issues/1700), but this has not solved the problem. For some reason, the processor still won't pick up the message from the RabbitQueue.

- In the Message Processor, the parameter 'Processor State' is set to active. (Or true, rather.)

```
<messageProcessor class="org.apache.synapse.message.processor.impl.forwarder.ScheduledMessageForwardingProcessor" messageStore="UserRegistrationMS" name="UserRegistrationMP" targetEndpoint="UserRegistrationEP" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <parameter name="client.retry.interval">1000</parameter>
    <parameter name="max.delivery.attempts">4</parameter>
    <parameter name="member.count">1</parameter>
    <parameter name="message.processor.reply.sequence">UserRegistrationResponseSeq</parameter>
    <parameter name="message.processor.fault.sequence">UserRegistrationErrorSeq</parameter>
    <parameter name="store.connection.retry.interval">1000</parameter>
    <parameter name="max.store.connection.attempts">-1</parameter>
    <parameter name="max.delivery.drop">Disabled</parameter>
    <parameter name="interval">1000</parameter>
 </messageProcessor>
```

- The Message Service:

```
<messageStore class="org.apache.synapse.message.store.impl.rabbitmq.RabbitMQStore" name="UserRegistrationMS" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <parameter name="store.rabbitmq.host.name">localhost</parameter>
    <parameter name="store.producer.guaranteed.delivery.enable">false</parameter>
    <parameter name="store.rabbitmq.host.port">5672</parameter>
    <parameter name="store.rabbitmq.route.key"/>
    <parameter name="store.rabbitmq.username">guest</parameter>
    <parameter name="store.rabbitmq.virtual.host"/>
    <parameter name="rabbitmq.connection.ssl.enabled">false</parameter>
    <parameter name="store.rabbitmq.exchange.name"/>
    <parameter name="store.rabbitmq.queue.name">UserRegistrationQueue</parameter>
    <parameter name="store.rabbitmq.password">guest</parameter>
</messageStore>
```

This is my console output

```
[2022-08-09 16:13:15,384]  INFO {RabbitMQSender} - RABBITMQ Sender started
[2022-08-09 16:13:15,426]  INFO {RabbitMQSender} - RabbitMQ AMQP Transport Sender initialized...
[2022-08-09 16:13:17,380]  INFO {EndpointDeployer} - Endpoint named 'UserRegistrationEP' has been deployed from file : C:\Programs\WSO2-Integration-Studio-8.1.0-win32-x86_64\IntegrationStudio\runtime\microesb\tmp\carbonapps\-1234\1660054397262TestCompositeApplication_1.0.0.car\UserRegistrationEP_1.0.0\UserRegistrationEP-1.0.0.xml
[2022-08-09 16:13:17,408]  INFO {SequenceDeployer} - Sequence named 'UserRegistrationErrorSeq' has been deployed from file : C:\Programs\WSO2-Integration-Studio-8.1.0-win32-x86_64\IntegrationStudio\runtime\microesb\tmp\carbonapps\-1234\1660054397262TestCompositeApplication_1.0.0.car\UserRegistrationErrorSeq_1.0.0\UserRegistrationErrorSeq-1.0.0.xml
[2022-08-09 16:13:17,459]  INFO {SequenceDeployer} - Sequence named 'UserRegistrationResponseSeq' has been deployed from file : C:\Programs\WSO2-Integration-Studio-8.1.0-win32-x86_64\IntegrationStudio\runtime\microesb\tmp\carbonapps\-1234\1660054397262TestCompositeApplication_1.0.0.car\UserRegistrationResponseSeq_1.0.0\UserRegistrationResponseSeq-1.0.0.xml
[2022-08-09 16:13:17,470]  INFO {MessageStoreFactory} - Successfully added Message Store configuration of : [UserRegistrationMS].
[2022-08-09 16:13:17,580]  INFO {RabbitMQStore} - Store [UserRegistrationMS] Successfully connected to RabbitMQ Broker
[2022-08-09 16:13:17,596]  INFO {RabbitMQStore} - Store [UserRegistrationMS]. Initialized... 
[2022-08-09 16:13:17,603]  INFO {MessageStoreDeployer} - Message Store named 'UserRegistrationMS' has been deployed from file : C:\Programs\WSO2-Integration-Studio-8.1.0-win32-x86_64\IntegrationStudio\runtime\microesb\tmp\carbonapps\-1234\1660054397262TestCompositeApplication_1.0.0.car\UserRegistrationMS_1.0.0\UserRegistrationMS-1.0.0.xml
[2022-08-09 16:13:17,803]  INFO {MessageProcessorDeployer} - Message Processor named 'UserRegistrationMP' has been deployed from file : C:\Programs\WSO2-Integration-Studio-8.1.0-win32-x86_64\IntegrationStudio\runtime\microesb\tmp\carbonapps\-1234\1660054397262TestCompositeApplication_1.0.0.car\UserRegistrationMP_1.0.0\UserRegistrationMP-1.0.0.xml
[2022-08-09 16:13:17,809]  INFO {API} - {api:MockAPI} Initializing API: MockAPI
[2022-08-09 16:13:17,813]  INFO {APIDeployer} - API named 'MockAPI' has been deployed from file : C:\Programs\WSO2-Integration-Studio-8.1.0-win32-x86_64\IntegrationStudio\runtime\microesb\tmp\carbonapps\-1234\1660054397262TestCompositeApplication_1.0.0.car\MockAPI_1.0.0\MockAPI-1.0.0.xml
[2022-08-09 16:13:17,816]  INFO {API} - {api:UserRegistrationAPI} Initializing API: UserRegistrationAPI
[2022-08-09 16:13:17,816]  INFO {APIDeployer} - API named 'UserRegistrationAPI' has been deployed from file : C:\Programs\WSO2-Integration-Studio-8.1.0-win32-x86_64\IntegrationStudio\runtime\microesb\tmp\carbonapps\-1234\1660054397262TestCompositeApplication_1.0.0.car\UserRegistrationAPI_1.0.0\UserRegistrationAPI-1.0.0.xml
[2022-08-09 16:13:17,817]  INFO {CappDeployer} - Successfully Deployed Carbon Application : GettingStartedGuaranteedCompositeExporter_1.0.0-SNAPSHOT{super-tenant}
[2022-08-09 16:13:17,819]  INFO {AppDeployerServiceComponent} - Dashboard is configured. Initiating heartbeat component.
[2022-08-09 16:13:17,857]  INFO {PassThroughListeningIOReactorManager} - Pass-through HTTP Listener started on 0.0.0.0:8290
[2022-08-09 16:13:17,864]  INFO {PassThroughListeningIOReactorManager} - Pass-through HTTPS Listener started on 0.0.0.0:8253
[2022-08-09 16:13:17,866]  INFO {StartupFinalizer} - WSO2 Micro Integrator started in 9,51 seconds
[2022-08-09 16:13:18,033]  INFO {PassThroughListeningIOReactorManager} - Pass-through EI_INTERNAL_HTTP_INBOUND_ENDPOINT Listener started on 0.0.0.0:9201
[2022-08-09 16:13:18,053]  INFO {PassThroughListeningIOReactorManager} - Pass-through EI_INTERNAL_HTTPS_INBOUND_ENDPOINT Listener started on 0.0.0.0:9164
[2022-08-09 16:13:18,147]  INFO {AbstractQuartzTaskManager} - Task scheduled: [ESB_TASK][MSMP_UserRegistrationMP_0] [Paused].
[2022-08-09 16:13:18,147]  INFO {ScheduledMessageProcessor} - Started message processor. [UserRegistrationMP].
[2022-08-09 16:13:19,873]  INFO {AuthenticationHandlerAdapter} - User admin logged in successfully
[2022-08-09 16:13:20,557]  INFO {AuthenticationHandlerAdapter} - User admin logged in successfully
```

Comment: check for case sensitivity errors when connecting to the queue.

Comment: Make sure the process that reads the queue is running. #wehavealldoneit

Comment: In your Message processor configuration can you check whether the Message Processor is in "Active"?

Comment: Show us your artifacts or the guide you followed.

Comment: Main ticket is updated with pertinent information.

Comment: Can you check whether it is related to this issue https://github.com/wso2/micro-integrator/issues/1700? If that is the case, please delete the relevant .properties file.

Comment: Deleting the relevant propeties file does solve the problem with the Message Processor instantly deactivating. However, the processor still refuses to pick up any messages from the queue. The search continues...

Comment: The problem was caused by a concurrent implementation of the jms.listener and the rabbitmq in the micro integrator server configuration. Commenting out the references to JMS caused the RabbitMQ-processor to work without any issue.